# using java epoch seconds in negative

Tags: java, epoch, java.util.date

I m writing a program which involves converting java.util.Date to java.sql.Date...

I've done it using getTime() method...

```
           java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
           java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
           dt=df.parse("06/12/0785");
           java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(dt.getTime());
           System.out.print("\n\n\n "+dt.getTime()+"    "+sqldate);
```

I m getting a negative value for `dt.getTime()` and the value is correct for `sqldate`...

The doubt i've is

```
           `Is it safe to use negative seconds as epoch or is it vulnerable to bugs while implementing it in database in any way.....???
```

***AND***

It's printing wrong date for sqldate on setting date as `00/00/0000` instead of the one mentioned in the example....what might be the cause......and does there lie a solution.......???

Comment: Java epoch of 0 is 1970, you have a year of 0785.

Comment: @JonLin k....agreed...actually i just wanna know using negative seconds as in this case is safer..and..how can enter a date like 0000-00-00 as a value for java.sql.Date or is it not at all possible....coz i want to set this date as default for mysql..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you parse a "00" as month, it will be regarded as December. The day "00" is the last day of the previous month, so the combinations is parsed as the 30th of November. As for the zero year, see [Year 0000 in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440480/year-0000-in-java). Negative values for .getTime() are no problem at all.

Comment: well..thanks to a proper reply..but..are you sure.....coz m planning to use them thoroughly...?

Comment: It is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28long%29) that negative numbers are valid constructor arguments for java.sql.Date. If you're in doubt whether it will work with your database, just check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in epoch time, "0" would be the equivalent to January 1, 1970.  Any date earlier than that would come out negative when you try to parse it.

Try changing the date string you are parsing to any date after 1970 and you will get a proper value.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says negative values are valid for java.sql.Date's constructor and setTime method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#setTime(long)

I expect that using "00/00/0000" as a date is a problem as there is no zero month, day, or year.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(year)

Comment: Yes, if you use 01/01/0001 in the example it works just fine.

Comment: Safe enough for which?  If you're just using it in memory it's fine.  If you're using a database that understands sql.Date then it should work, unless it explicitly disclaims that it doesn't.  If you're translating data through multiple implementations of Date types then it's possible that the conversion could be lossy if they have different capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) is outdated and error-prone. Let's first understand how `SimpleDateFormat` erroneously processes a string like `00/00/0000` and later we will cover how the modern date-time API prevents an attempt to processes an invalid string like this.

The following demo will help us understand easily both, the concept and the problem:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        SimpleDateFormat sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yG", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(sdfOutput.format(sdfInput.parse("00/00/2021")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
30 November 2020AD
```

**Some facts about `SimpleDateFormat`:**

- `SimpleDateFormat` processes the month, `1` as `January`.
- It processes the year, month and day-of-month in a circular fashion which is very similar to how `int`, and `long` are processed.

[image]

For the sake of completeness, look at the output of the following statements:

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1); // -2147483648
System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1); // 2147483647
```

Based on this concept, this is how `SimpleDateFormat` has parsed `00/00/2021`:

- **Month, `00`:** Go back to the last month i.e. December which also means the year will become 2020.
- **Day-of-month, `00`:** Go back to the last day of the last month which also means December will shift back one place to become November and the last day of November is 30.

Thus, the output will be  `30 November 2020AD`.

**Quiz:** What will be the output for the input string, `-01/-01/2021`?

If your answer is: `30 October 2020AD`, you have understood it correctly.

Given below are some more examples:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yG", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(sdfOutput.format(sdfInput.parse("00/00/0000"))); // 30 November 2BC
System.out.println(sdfOutput.format(sdfInput.parse("00/-01/2021"))); // 31 October 2020AD
System.out.println(sdfOutput.format(sdfInput.parse("00/13/2021"))); // 31 December 2021AD
System.out.println(sdfOutput.format(sdfInput.parse("00/14/2021"))); // 31 January 2022AD
```

**Why `2BC`?**

Luckily<sup>1.</sup> there is no year-0. Before 1AD, we have 1BC. So, we know year-0 as 1BC. If you go one year back, it will be 2BC. You would like to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) for some more explanation.

You will encounter many such surprises while using the legacy date-time API. For these reasons, it is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

## *java.time*

Let's see how `java.time`, the modern API prevents an attempt to processes an invalid string like this:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate.parse("00/00/0000", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
> Text '00/00/0000' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear
> (valid values 1 - 12): 0

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>2.</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>1. Otherwise, it would have opened a can of worms regarding whether year-0 should be called 0AD or 0BC.</sup>

<sup>2. For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>